# PC turns on(sends signal to LCD and gives BIOS beep) after random number of attempts

Tags: graphics-card, bios, lcd, boot

My PC worked well until one time about 6 months ago the LCD lost signal and I have to restart the it.

Since then when I want to turn on the computer and push the power button I do not get signal on the LCD and there is NO beep from BIOS. But if I turn off the computer by switch at the back(AC adapter's switch) off then on and then turn on the PC it will work normally: sometimes even after second attempt, sometimes it is fiftenth. I didn't do with it anything because I use this PC once a week but I do not want it to be damaged permanently. I write from this PC right now.

Then there is short double beep and standard screen like (below - it is not my screenshot but I do have BIOS for MSI P4N SLIT 7160) and everything works great. The PC was produced in 2005. I do not think it is AC adapter fault, but of course I can be wrong. It is chieftec 400W.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There's a few things that could be happening.

Is the harddrive from 2005 as well? If so, it is likely failing or becoming damaged, as harddrives do; and it is very likely to crash completely, corrupting all its data and stop working entirely at any minute. Impending doom!

This sounds more likely to be a power supply problem. They are very cheap to replace, but if it is failing, there is a chance that using a broken power supply could damage your CPU. I know this is old equipment, but you should be aware of the potential risks at hand.

Have you verified the cable connections inside the PC? It is possible that something has come loose, like the power cable to the motherboard, or a silly fan cable.

It is also possible that the RAM is failing or improperly connected. You may want to try removing it and reinserting it fully.

One way to check further what might be happening is to look in Windows Device Manager in the Control Panel when the computer does boot. Check if the RAM, CPU and devices are detected correctly. If any devices are reported as functioning anomalously, then that might be a starting point for further investigation.

Answer (score 2):

This is a desktop PC? You refer to "switch on the back" which sounds like a desktop, but you also refer to a power adapter, which sounds more like a laptop.

At a quick guess, Broadly, old age - it's 9 years old, computers don't live forever. Especially ones built in the "Counterfeit capacitor era" (and who knows if we are beyond that even now...)

Less broadly is hard to be sure of without swapping some parts and seeing where the problem changes. Could be a bad power supply. Could be a bad (button) switch. Could be a bad motherboard, or more narrowly than that based on common issues, a bad capacitor (or a bunch of them) on the mother board.

Comment: I guess this is the correct answer, failing capacitors often cause exactly this problem. Here are [some photos of leaking capacitors](http://www.capacitorlab.com/visible-failures/). If you can see any like this on your motherboard, then it's time to replace it.